# numeric sort with unique option does not show 0!

Tags: sort, numeric-data, uniq

I have a file with many redundant numbers in each row. Imagine something like the below:

```
echo "10
9
5
6
4
cell
3
2
0
7
0
1" > test
```

When I use `sort -un test` I get the following output:

```
cell
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
9
10
```

while I expect the below (I mean `0` as a first row of the output):

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
9
10
```

Applying the `sort -n` and then redirecting to `uniq` doesn't make such a mess, however, it shows the non-numeric lines.
Is there any way to just use the `sort` with `-nu` to get `0` at the first line instead of an alphanumeric token?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sort (difference between default and numerical option -n)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/382798/sort-difference-between-default-and-numerical-option-n)

Comment: From the accepted answer to the above: “Lines that begin non-numerically are sorted as if they were zero”. POSIX [says](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html) “An empty digit string shall be treated as zero.”

Comment: @StephenKitt Thanks.